# How to shutdown computer in matlab scripts?

Tags: matlab

I want to shutdown my computer in matlab scripts when the program has ran to end. Is there any commands about this?

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:
`system('shutdown -s');`

You can also try the following function as posted in [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8783-turn-off-your-windows-computer-from-within-matlab-after-a-long-unattended-calculation/content/shutdown.m).

```
function shutdown(varargin)
if nargin
   if isnumeric(varargin{1})
       if varargin{1} == -1
           evalc('!shutdown -a');
           return
       end
       t = ceil(varargin{1});
    else
       t = 60;
    end
else
   t = 60;
end
eval(['!shutdown -s -f -t ' num2str(t)])
```

**USAGE:**

- `shutdown`          = turn off the computer in 60 seconds
- `shutdown(numsec)`  = turn off the computer in numsec seconds
- `shutdown(-1)`      = abort the shutdown; don't turn off the computer
- `numsec` = optional number of seconds to pause after system shutdown
          window is displayed (defualt is 60 seconds). If numsec is
          -1, then the command aborts a shutdown countdown currently
          in progress.

Answer (score 2):

This one should work on windows, linux and mac. However your matlab should be running under a superuser/adminsitrator account

```
if ispc
    !shutdown -s -f -t 0
else
    !shutdown -h now
end
```